# Create bash script to open URL in Mac OS X

Tags: osx-lion, automator

I want to OS X to intelligently open `git` URLs by first trying to open their repo page on [GitHub](http://github.com), and then falling back to something like [GitBox.app](http://gitboxapp.com/).

I found [this question](/questions/239231/osx-open-with-bash-script) extremely helpful, and I created an Automator app to wrap a bash script (which does all of the intelligent stuff), and used [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to set OS X to use my automator app to open `git://` URLs.

This didn't work, so I tried some debugging.  I set my bash script to output its arguments to `/tmp/output.txt`, and it turns out that **the script isn't getting any command line arguments**.  If I set OS X to use this same automator app as the default app for `*.txt` files, the bash script correctly gets the path of the file as the first argument, but it doesn't work with URLs.  Any idea how to get this to work?

Also, I'm running 10.7.

**Edit:** Here's a snapshot of the Automator app:
[image: Automator app]

And here's the text of that simple bash script (not what I would actually use to open the `git://` URLs, but it demonstrates the lack of arguments:

```
rm -f /tmp/output.txt
echo $0 >> /tmp/output.txt
echo $* >> /tmp/output.txt
```

And the only output I get in `/tmp/output.txt` is:

```
-
```

Comment: Might be helpful to post your script and/or Automator app here for others to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work like that, because OS X doesn't treat files, folders, and URLs, which are just command line arguments to the associated programs on other systems, like other platforms. Automator programs *really* only can handle files and folders.

---

You need to create an AppleScript based application, which responds to `open location`.

Open AppleScript Editor, and paste the following code (changing the script of course):

```
on open location myURL
    do shell script "echo " & myURL & " > /Users/danielbeck/test"
end open location
```

Save *as application*. Then select the application bundle you just created, right-click, *Show Package Contents*, and edit `Contents/Info.plist` using a text editor (after converting to XML using `plutil` on the command line, if it's binary), or the default editor which is part of Apple's Developer Tools.

Add the following to its top-level structure (the screenshot is how it looks like in current Xcode, the XML is what you'd add in a text editor):

> [image]

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>openme</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>AppleScript Testing URL</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

That will associate `openme://` URLs with that application. Save, move the program to a different folder and back to update Launch Services, and test it by typing an `openme://` URL into a web browser's address bar:

> [image]

You'll want to replace `openme` by `git` and the `echo` call by your shell script, of course.

Comment: So does that application automatically register for the `git` protocol or do you have to change the Launch Services association? As for updating Launch Services, shouldn't it be enough to `touch` the `.app`?

Comment: @slhck It will automatically register the `git://` scheme (like I did for the `openme://` scheme), but use of RCDefaultApp or something similar might be necessary to grab it from a different Git client (similar to associating a file type with a viewer, just without UI). `touch` works fine for updating Launch Services, I usually just don't have a Terminal window open at that point and drag&drop in Finder, `Cmd-Z` to undo, is usually faster.

Comment: @slhck I messed up my user profile so much working out all these SU answers it's not even funny, so I try to not use "productive" file extensions, URL schemes, etc. whenever possible. You don't even want to see my services folder :-)

Comment: Regarding the Terminal window: If you don't know it yet, you could try [DTerm](http://decimus.net/DTerm). And I saw your services context menu in a recent screenshot – I was like, … what? :)

Comment: @slhck Thanks for the link! Regarding the services menu, that one was already filtered, actually. Only about half the *Files and Folders* services are checked. I have 64 items in `~/Library/Services`, a folder that does not exist by default ;-)

Comment: is it possible to place the shell script in the *.app directory (maybe *.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts)?  How do I reference that relative path from within the applescript?

Comment: @aaron `tell application "System Events" to set _file to application file of item 1 of (every application process whose frontmost is true)` and `POSIX path of _file & "/Contents/Resources/yourscript"` will work for AppleScript *applications* that are of course frontmost when run. Open a new question and let me know about it if you require a more thorough explanation.